# Create File Upload control using HTML controls

Tags: html, file-upload, controls, asp.net-2.0

I am facing an issue with asp.net file upload control inside update panel.

That is FileUploadControl.HasFile always return "true".

Can we create a "file upload" control (which has "browse button") using html controls...and use it inside asp.net 2.0 ???

Comment: File upload (<input type="file" />) doesn't do AJAX, I suspect that's the problem?

Comment: I need an html control to replace the ASP.net fileUpload control.

Comment: There's nothing to replace with, I'm afraid. (At least not native, by HTML spec.) The common solution is to have your file upload inside an iframe, or similar. Btw, you should stop talking about "controls", it's still html you are working with. Use google, I've found a blog post about a solution: http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input type="file" />`?